# get the sum/combined values using parseFloast

Tags: sum, parsefloat

i have been trying to figure out how to get *the sum of the 3 inventory totals* using *parseFloat*

**"extract1" field** would represent the sum of *already extracted data* from the "In_Stock", "Stock_national" and "Stock_24H" fields, which should = 14 (0+3+11) but instead is showing 113 as a result of the combined values.

**how should i write this in order for it to show 14 as total?** this is a final step for me in be able to complete an automated inventory update process and would greatly appreciate any help!

```
parseFloat(In_Stock+Stock_national+Stock_24H)
```

and shows this in json format

```
{
"ID":[
{
"name":"185/65R15 88T BFG ADVANTAGE T/A SPORT",
"sku":"98559",
"Product_Number":"98559.1",
"In_Stock":"0",
"Stock_24H":"3",
"Stock_national":"11",
"selection2":[
{
"name":"0"
},
{
"name":"3"
},
{
"name":"11"
}
],
"extract1":113
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, need to convert each variable to a number by calling parseFloat() around each one and it shows total addition of numbers.

parseFloat(In_Stock) + parseFloat(Stock_24H) + parseFloat(Stock_national)

resulsts **note: (extract1 replaced with id_stock_total)**

```
{
"ID":[
{
"name":"185/65R15 88T BFG ADVANTAGE T/A SPORT",
"sku":"98559",
"Product_Number":"98559.1",
"In_Stock":"0",
"Stock_24H":"3",
"Stock_national":"11",
"id_stock_total":14
},
```

Comment: FYI: This was used in the "extract box" where parseFloat expressions can be used to manipulate data extracted after a Scrape/Run with PARSEHUB Scraper